# Java SQLite добавление column

Tags: java, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу добавить ряд full_name в имеющуюся базу данных, в месте COLUMN высвечивает "unrecognized statement"  , в чем может быть проблема,  подскажите?

```
public static void addColumn() {

    try {

        st = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "ALTER TABLE applicants ADD COLUMN full_name TEXT";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);


        st.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Высвечивает где? В среде разработки? Или кидает эксепшн при выполнении?

Comment: @РоманДанилов  в среде разработке , в InteliJ, при выполнении SQL error or missing database (duplicate column name: full_name)

Comment: Дубликат колонки full_name он вам говорит. Значит колонка уже существует.

Comment: В том то и дело, что не существует..

Comment: СУБД какая? Попробуйте без слова COLUMN.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko попробовал, не помогло , все тот же "unrecognized statemenе 1",   SQLite

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `;` в конец запроса. Т.е. `ALTER TABLE applicants ADD COLUMN full_name TEXT;`

Comment: @matrix и так не работает  ..

Comment: добавил скрин проблемы в описании

Comment: Покажите тогда сразу и полный текст ошибки

Comment: @matrix загрузил, посмотрите

Comment: Выполните в контексте базы запрос `PRAGMA table_info(applicants);` и покажите вывод.

Comment: @matrix оказалось все работает , все добавляется. Теперь не понимаю почему в среде разработки подсвечивает, спасибо!

Comment: @ValekPotapov, конечно работает) Ошибка дубликата колонки об этом сразу сказала. Среда разработки на самом деле не самая умная штука. Возможно у вас не выбран SQL-диалект в среде разработки и она не знает, что это за оператор